# r - ggplot multiple line graphs using all column as x and all row as y

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a tbl_df that looks like

```
| Type| 2015 | 2016 | 2017 |2018 |
| One  | 10000| 165274| 268709| 332536|
| Two  | 6763 | 46996 | 59183 | 34896 |
| Three| 8316 | 23347 | 45878 | 49054 |
```

How can I use ggplot to make a multiple line graph, with each column that has year as the x-axis, and each Type as a new line, as the y axis? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ggplot` it is convenient to plot if you bring the data in long format.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value, color = Type, group = Type)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x = 'Year', y = 'Value', 
       title = "Values for different types")
```

[image]